# Django admin site: prevent fields from being edited?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

is it possible to prevent certain fields to be edited after they've been saved?
They should be editable when the user creates a new item of a certain model but then when they try to open them to edit certain fields are 'blocked'.

thanks

Answer (score 10):

You could override your ModelAdmin's `get_readonly_fields` to set certain fields readonly:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj: # when editing an object
            return ['field1']
        return self.readonly_fields
```

Comment: Hi could you please explain your example a bit more? I'm very new to Django. How does your code checks if the document (model instance) being opened is opened for the first time (creation) or successively (edit) ? I need some fields (not all) to be editable when the instance is created and blocked the following times the instance is opened for editing. thanks!

Comment: This is really great, but it doesn't seem to work for inlines. For some reason, when I use this function in an inline, it makes the field read-only, even when creating objects.