# get_readonly_fields in a TabularInline class in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to use get_readonly_fields in a TabularInline class in Django:

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item
    extra = 5

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            return ['name']

        return self.readonly_fields
```

This code was taken from another StackOverflow question:
[Django admin site: prevent fields from being edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918453/django-admin-site-prevent-fields-from-being-edited)

However, when it's put in a TabularInline class, the new object forms don't render properly.  The goal is to make certain fields read only while still allowing data to be entered in new objects.  Any ideas for a workaround or different strategy?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "Don't render properly"?

Comment: There aren't any form fields for new object rows, and the "name" column is repeated for existing objects.

Comment: have the same problem.. it seems to be that the obj that is passed is that of the main object, not the inline object

Answer (score 24):

Careful - "obj" is not the inline object, it's the parent. That's arguably a bug - see for example [this Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15602)

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround to this issue I have associated a form and a Widget to my Inline:

admin.py:

```
...

class MasterCouponFileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MasterCouponFile
    form = MasterCouponFileForm
    extra = 0
```

in Django 2.0:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from . import models
from feedback.widgets import DisablePopulatedText


class FeedbackCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MasterCouponFile
        fields = ('Comment', ....)
        widgets = {
            'Comment':  DisablePopulatedText,
        }
```

in widgets.py

```
from django import forms

class DisablePopulatedText(forms.TextInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        """Render the widget as an HTML string."""
        if value is not None:
            # Just return the value, as normal read_only fields do
            # Add Hidden Input otherwise the old fields are still required
            HiddenInput = forms.HiddenInput()
            return format_html("{}\n"+HiddenInput.render(name, value), self.format_value(value))
        else:
            return super().render(name, value, attrs, renderer)
```

older Django Versions:

forms.py

```
....

class MasterCouponFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MasterCouponFile       

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MasterCouponFileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['range'].widget = DisablePopulatedText(self.instance)
        self.fields['quantity'].widget = DisablePopulatedText(self.instance)
```

in widgets.py

```
...

from django import forms
from django.forms.util import flatatt
from django.utils.encoding import force_text

class DisablePopulatedText(forms.TextInput):
    def __init__(self, obj, attrs=None):
        self.object = obj
        super(DisablePopulatedText, self).__init__(attrs)
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if value is None:
            value = ''
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, type=self.input_type, name=name)
        if value != '':
            # Only add the 'value' attribute if a value is non-empty.
            final_attrs['value'] = force_text(self._format_value(value))
        if "__prefix__" not in name and not value:
            return format_html('<input{0} disabled />', flatatt(final_attrs))
        else:
            return format_html('<input{0} />', flatatt(final_attrs))
```

Comment: This answer helped me immensely and is probably the best way to get this done.

Answer (score 2):

This is still currently not easily doable due to the fact that obj is the parent model instance not the instance displayed by the inline.

What I did in order to solve this, was to make all the fields, in the inline form, read only  and provide a Add/Edit link to a ChangeForm for the inlined model.

Like this

```
class ChangeFormLinkMixin(object):
    def change_form_link(self, instance):
        url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (instance._meta.app_label,
            instance._meta.module_name), args=(instance.id,))
        # Id == None implies and empty inline object
        url = url.replace('None', 'add')
        command = _('Add') if url.find('add') > -1 else _('Edit')
        return format_html(u'<a href="{}">%s</a>' % command, url)
```

And then in the inline I will have something like this

```
class ItemInline(ChangeFormLinkMixin, admin.StackedInline):
    model = Item
    extra = 5
    readonly_fields = ['field1',...,'fieldN','change_form_link']
```

Then in the ChangeForm I'll be able to control the changes the way I want to (I have several states, each of them with a set of editable fields associated).

Comment: I still see this as an ugly hack because the user can change the parent in the child's change form, but then again, the admin site is pretended to be used by "trusted" users.

Answer (score 1):

As others have added, this is a design flaw in django as seen in [this Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15602) (thanks Danny W). `get_readonly_fields` returns the parent object, which is not what we want here.

Since we can't make it readonly, here is my solution to validate it can't be set by the form, using a formset and a clean method:

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item
    formset = ItemInlineFormset

class ItemInlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super(ItemInlineFormset, self).clean()
        for form in self.forms:
            if form.instance.some_condition:
                form.add_error('some_condition', 'Nope')
```

Comment: I know this is pretty old but I'm desperate. Do you have any advice on how to make this method work with a manytomany relationship instead of foreign key? Your solution raises the error when I save the changes even though the record that I wanted to update was accepted

Answer (score -2):

You are on the right track. Update self.readonly_fields with a tuple of what fields you want to set as readonly.

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item
    extra = 5

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        # add a tuple of readonly fields
        self.readonly_fields += ('field_a', 'field_b')
        return self.readonly_fields
```

Comment: This isn't the problem. The problem he's having is the obj holds the parent object, not the inline object. Ultimately, he cannot make fields readonly in an existing row but allow the field to be editable on insert.