# Django admin - different readonly fields of Inline admin form depending on change or add

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to have different `readonly_fields` on an inline admin depending on whether we are adding or changing an instance of the inline model.  For a regular (not inline) admin class, this would be the way:

```
class SomeInlineAdmin(admin.StackedInline):

     def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        # normally this will tell you if you're adding or changing an instance 
        if obj:
            # change
        else:
            # add
        # but... obj is instance of parent class, not the inline model class...
```

But I don't see a way to determine inside the InlineAdmin whether we are adding or changing the inline model instance.  Tangentially, I find it very strange that in the InlineAdmin class, `obj` is an instance of the parent model, not the inline model.

Any ideas?

Comment: Create custom widget and put logic there http://stackoverflow.com/a/25182680/3033586

Answer (score 0):

I did this with foreign key relations:
add to the child class a field that holds parent PK, and when needed i could query the parent field values.
or - add a same field to child and update it when ever the parent updates.

Comment: The code without the wording is always better than the wording without the code. I mean that I did not understand what the solution you describe is all about. Could you please give an example?